# Trying to create a single report with multiple outer joins

Tags: ms-access, report

I'm new to Access with close to no knowledge in coding besides a few basic syntax. All I know comes from what I could find through the Internet.

I'm trying to create a report on the performance of academics based on their publications, grants and number of students. I have no problem creating all 3 reports individually but I've been requested to combine all 3 into a single report. The report needs to include all academics regardless if they have any publications, grants or students, AND must generate it in such a way that it is grouped based on each individual academic. I'm not very good with explanations but it should look something like this:

**Academic 1**

- Publications
- Grants
- Students

**Academic 2**

- Publications
- Grants
- Students

The relationship is something like this (sorry if the explanation is bad):

[**Academics**] 1-M [**Supervision**] M-1 [**Students**]

[**Academics**] 1-M [**Published**] M-1 [**Publications**]

[**Academics**] 1-M [**Funding**] M-1 [**Grants**]

The tables on the "1" side of the relationship have a primary key that is linked together by the tables in between. Academics have more than one grant, publication and student, and it is a report which is supposed to span a couple of years.

I've tried grouping based on Academic and placing subreports in the same group. Sadly, there are multiples of the same record for each subreport (e.g. the same publication will repeat itself several times) regardless if the query records themselves are distinct or if I've grouped them based on publication, etc.

Comment: Is your report supposed to show counts (i.e.# students, # grants, # pub's) or show values (i.e. student names, individual grants, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The following is one way to get counts for your report -- assuming you want counts or sums or some combination:

Create three queries (maybe like you already have) where each query will join 'Academics' to one of the relationship tables (Supervision, Publishing, Funding). Make these 'Totals' queries where you 'GroupBy the unique field in 'Academics', and 'Count' some field in the other table.  i.e. I named these Q1, Q2, Q3

```
  SELECT Academics.AName, Count(Supervision.AName) AS Students
      FROM Academics 
      INNER JOIN Supervision ON Academics.AName = Supervision.AName
      GROUP BY Academics.AName;
```

Create a fourth query to be used in the report that joins 'Academics' and  Q1, Q2, Q3 like follows:

```
SELECT Academics.AName, Sum(Q1.Students) AS Students, Sum(Q2.Publications) AS Pubs, 
Sum(Q3.Funding) AS Funds
    FROM ((Academics 
    LEFT JOIN Q1 ON Academics.AName = Q1.AName)
    LEFT JOIN Q2 ON Academics.AName = Q2.AName) 
    LEFT JOIN Q3 ON Academics.AName = Q3.AName
    GROUP BY Academics.AName;
```

This will return ALL Academics - even if no students, funds, or pubs. You can set a filter to only include an Academic if they have a related record.